# TypeScript | Detect import is a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to create a TypeScript plugin (based on https://github.com/nvandamme/typescript-transformer-append-js-extension) that appends `.js` extension to an imported/exported file or adds `index.js` to an imported/exported directory:

```js
// Before
import hello from './world';
import { test } from './directory';

// After
import hello from './world.js';
import { test } from './directory/index.js';
```

The following code (only) works for imported/exported files:

```js
import typescript from "typescript";

export default function transformer(_: typescript.Program) {
  return (transformationContext: typescript.TransformationContext) =>
    (sourceFile: typescript.SourceFile) => {
      function visitNode(node: typescript.Node): typescript.VisitResult<typescript.Node> {
        if (shouldMutateModuleSpecifier(node)) {
          const newModuleSpecifier = typescript.factory.createStringLiteral(
            `${node.moduleSpecifier.text}.js`,
          );

          if (typescript.isImportDeclaration(node)) {
            return typescript.factory.updateImportDeclaration(
              node,
              node.modifiers,
              node.importClause,
              newModuleSpecifier,
              undefined,
            );
          }

          if (typescript.isExportDeclaration(node)) {
            return typescript.factory.updateExportDeclaration(
              node,
              node.modifiers,
              false,
              node.exportClause,
              newModuleSpecifier,
              undefined,
            );
          }
        }

        return typescript.visitEachChild(node, visitNode, transformationContext);
      }

      return typescript.visitNode(sourceFile, visitNode);
    };
}
```

I don't know how to detect if the import declaration is a directory. 
Is there a built-in function, a node's property, or are there other methods that have this knowledge? 
Thanks!

Comment: It's impossible to see from only inspecting the code. You will need to actually resolve the path and see whether you find a file or a directory there. (At best, the typescript compiler might know which typescript files are contained in the project)

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your response. Can you guide me on how to transform the declaration to an absolute path? Thanks again

Comment: See [`typescript-transformer-esm`](https://github.com/carlocorradini/typescript-transformer-esm)